# Azure App Publishing - I think Javascript isn't enabled, but honestly I have no clue

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've written and deployed a web form app (Visual Studio) and deployed it to my Azure platform which is running app services.

The problem is I think a Javascript setting isn't quit right as the login form isn't displaying correctly and the buttons don't fire any java functions.

Here's how the page looks when I view it while debugging in VS2017

It's basically 3 forms, but 2 are hidden (by depending on which button you click)
[Debug Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pah8.png)

And here is what the page looks like when I view after publishing on the Azure platform. Any ideas what I need to change to always get it to display and behave the same as when run via localhost? 
[Azure Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPwTV.png)

Update: These errors show under F12:

[Javascript Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdg1.png)

[Javascript Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANwU8.png)

Comment: By the way: do you mean Java or Javascript?

Comment: @Jorge_B Ah - yeah I mean Javascript. 
Can you point me to which settings I'm best to check please?

Comment: Let me edit your post in order to attract the right people before ^^

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Could you just press F12 when browsing your web app to see whether there has errors under Console tab? And you need to make sure your JavaScript file has been successfully loaded.

Comment: Hi Bruce, If I hit F12, I get the below errors on all of the javascript resources: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I've added a screenshot to the original Question